# Handle HTTP request in C# Console application

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a Console application that works fine,but I want to add ability to handle http requests,first problem is I need to use another port like 1370 ,and the second issue: I don't want to use ASP.NET Web Service because it needs IIS.

Answer (score 3):

You have several alternatives:
a) use Microsoft way - self hosted WCF for this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

b) use open source - there's several flavors to choose from - ServiceStack (http://servicestack.net), open rasta (http://openrasta.org/)

c) do it from scratch, like using HttpListener or even at lower level, like sockets.

Comment: well, wcf has so many possibilities, that correct answer is it depends, because wcf can work in tcp mode, so sending tcp requests/receiving them from browser can be tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Use  [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) class and [this](http://www.csharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ialam/creatingwebserverincs12022005042042am/creatingwebserverincs.aspx) is good article

Comment: The Web Service will be called a lot,can I trust it?

Answer (score 0):

what about Web APi ? you can self host the web api. it's simple and light weight :)

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;      

var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
{
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412169.aspx). You'll be able to handle HTTP requests.