# How to create HTTP post request

Tags: c#, api, http, request

Hello I'm new at programing so my question might be a little bit odd. My boss ask me to create a HTTP post request using  a key and a message to access our client.

I already seen the article [Handle HTTP request in C# Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587847/handle-http-request-in-c-sharp-console-application)  but it doesn't include where I put the key and message so the client API knows its me. Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: depends how the api handles those values? As header data, or as query parameters? Also, please update your question with the code you have tried so far

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: He say that he already prepare the endpoint where I can test whether I can access there API thru HTTP post request at there demo site.

He mentioned to attached the key at the request header together with a message: Hello, I will receive a response "Welcome" if not 
"Get out". The key is about 400 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you wanted this:

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/page.aspx");

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "username=user";
postData += "&password=pass";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    // Append some custom header
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer some_key";

    string message = "some message to send";
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    byte[] result = client.UploadData(data);
}
```

Of course depending on how the API expects the data to be sent and which headers it requires you will have to adapt this code to match the requirements.

Comment: How do you add the URL to which you want to send.