# Making a call to a Web Api with a JObject in the body

Tags: c#

I want to, in code behind, call a Web Api I've built and save some data that I have stored in the following JObject:

```
var json = new JObject(
            new JProperty("firstName", txtFirstName.Text),
            new JProperty("lastName", txtLastName.Text),
            new JProperty("companyName", txtCompanyName.Text),
            new JProperty("email", txtEmail.Text),
            new JProperty("phone", txtPhone.Text)
        );
```

Problem is, I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I've found a plethora of examples that are close to the answer, but not quite what I'm looking for. So, how would someone construct an http call to a web api(in C#) and have the aforementioned JObject be posted in the body of the message? I wouldn't necessarily need anything returned, except maybe a generic success or failure message. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: Like that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314521/how-to-create-http-post-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the json into a .net object and got my problem solved.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

        var userData = new User()
        {
            firstName = txtFirstName.Text,
            lastName = txtLastName.Text,
            companyName = txtCompanyName.Text,
            email = txtEmail.Text,
            phone = txtPhone.Text
        };
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yourBaseUrlHere");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("requestUrlHere", user);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Success code
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using `System.Net.HttpClient`

```
 string jsonText = json.ToString();
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
      var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
      httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

      HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync("http://myWebUrl/send", httpContent);
 }
```